# Imaginary charge on black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, complex-numbers, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I was wondering if one can put an imaginary charge on a black hole. What I mean is, take a Reissner-Nordstörm black hole and make the charge $Q$ and therefore also the imaginary potential pure imaginary by senden mu->i mu.
Has someone ever read a paper about that kind of stuff?

Answer (score 3):

If we set the charge of Reissner–Nordström soultion purely imaginary, the metric would be well defined:
$$ {\displaystyle {\rm {d}}s^{2}=\left(1-{\frac {r_{\rm {s}}}{r}}-{\frac {r_{\rm {Q}}^{2}}{r^{2}}}\right){\rm {d}}t^{2}-\left(1-{\frac {r_{\rm {s}}}{r}}-{\frac {r_{\rm {Q}}^{2}}{r^{2}}}\right)^{-1}{\rm {d}}r^{2}-r^{2}\,{\rm {d}}\Omega ^{2},}
$$where $r_{\rm s}=2M$, $r_{\rm Q}=|Q|^2$ (in units $G=c=k=1$).
 However, making the EM potential purely imaginary ($A=i |Q| / r \,\mathrm{d} t$) would make the energy of EM field negative and therefore the solution is unphysical. Therefore the geometry is rarely considered in literature.

One exception is Andrew Hamilton's "proto-book" *General Relativity, Black Holes, and Cosmology* ([pdf online](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/courses/astr3740_17/grbook.pdf)) where he says the following (pp 202-203):

> What makes the geometry interesting is that the singularity, instead of being gravitationally  repulsive,  becomes  gravitationally  attractive.  Thus  particles,  instead  of  bouncing  off  the
>   singularity, are attracted to it, and it turns out to be possible to continue geodesics through the singularity.